# Why do I get different answers for $(s^2-9)(s^4-3s^2-2)=2(s^2-9)$ depending on how I do it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification

**Solve :**

$(s^2-9)(s^4-3s^2-2)=2(s^2-9)$

**Here is what I did :**

$(s^2-9)(s^4-3s^2-2)=2(s^2-9)$ , cancel the common term.

$(s^4-3s^2-2)=2$

Let $a=s^2$

$a^2-3s-2=2$

$a^2-3s-4=0$ , factorize & put back $s$

$(s+2)(s-2)(s^2+1)=0$

$s:\pm2, \pm i$

**Issue :**

The answer is meant to be $s:\pm2, \pm3, \pm i$.

Did I do something not illegal or make some mistake?

Comment: So you missed the case where $s^2-9=0$, where the first division is illegal.

Comment: So if I first solve $s^2-9$ then divided it where $s\neq\pm3$ then is it valid?

Comment: @OxPh yes, it will be valid if you do that

Comment: It might be newbie doubt , but it is valid doubt , hence not necessary to downvote. I will try to rectify with my +1 , either way , OP can get some learning "Points" out of the comments & answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 :**

We can not cancel the terms unless the terms are Non-Zero , because we can not divide both sides by Zero.
Hence , we have to treat it like :
Case 1 : Common term is $0$ , hence get the Equation $(s^2-9)=0$ & get the Solutions &
Case 2 : Common term is not $0$ , hence cancel it & get the Solutions
Putting that together , we will get all Solutions.

**Method 2 :**

When you got the Solutions $\pm i , \pm 2$ , you were setting the factors to $0$
You have to use that line of thinking at the Earlier Point it-self.

$(s^2-9)(s^4-3s^2-2)=2(s^2-9)$
$(s^2-9)(s^4-3s^2-2)-2(s^2-9)=0$
$(s^2-9)[(s^4-3s^2-2)-2]=0$
$(s-3)(s+3)[(s^4-3s^2-2)-2]=0$
$(s-3)(s+3)[\text{ all your other factors }]=0$

When you then set each factor to $0$ , you will get all Solutions :
$\pm i , \pm 2 , \pm 3$